# Copying an image file from one directory to another using php

Tags: php

I have a data table which contains the names of image files. What I am trying to do is loop through the table and
when a match is found by the query, copy the file from one location to another. When I run the script I get the following error:

Warning: copy(/conf_images/room/viridor-logo-595x298.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

I have checked that the file is present in "conf_images/room/" and it is.
I have checked that the destination directory is present, and it is.
I have read a number of posts but none of then deal with the same issue.

Can anyone see what would be causing the warning?

My code:

```
$source = "conf_images/room";
$destination = "conf_images/room/DTGLA";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM conf_image_depository WHERE HotelID = '". $HotelID. "' ";
$sqlfile = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlfile);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlfile)) {
    $newName = str_replace("_","",$row['ImageName']);
    copy($source."/".$newName, $destination."/".$newName);
}
```

if I echo $source, $newName, $destination and $newName I get:

```
$source =  /room/
$newName =  abec1.png
$destination /room/DTGLA/
$newName =  abec1.png
```

Comment: This is most likely caused by the directories that you have typed in. I would change the folders to they are relative to the folder where the PHP is being ran and not trying to go all the way back to the root.

Comment: Well the first question always has to be ... Did you check that the file exists in that path? And the second question is Do you have permission to acces it from the user running this code

Comment: Hi, I moved the script the "conf_images" directory. when the script is run I get the same warning. I have double checked that the file exists and the source and destination directories are correct. And I do have permissions access to both the source and destination directories.

Comment: can you show us what is the result of `print($source."/".$newName, $destination."/".$newName);` before you copy()?

Comment: _you_ might have permission, but does PHP? If you're running this in a web application, then PHP has the same permissions as the account under which the webserver runs. If you're having permission problems (or path problems for that matter) PHP should emit errors or warnings about it - make sure you've got PHP configured to log or display these

Comment: Hi, print ($source."/".$newName, $destination."/".$newName); causes an error when I try and save., At the start of the script I have "error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');"

Comment: And what error does that line cause?

Comment: Hi, The script will not save without Dreamweaver display a syntax error. If I just ignore Dreamweaver and save anyway, run the script and the bowser says HTTP ERROR 500 which I would expect.

Comment: And the underlying error is? If it just says 500 in the browser you have to check the PHP error log for the real error. Or tell us what exactly Dreamweaver is complaining about

Comment: Hi, It errors on the line "print ($source."/".$newName, $destination."/".$newName);" The underlying error is a syntax error, it just say "syntax error".

Comment: Hi, If I print each element I get SOURCE /room/ NEWNAME abec_1.png Destination /room/DTGLA/ Newname abec_1.png

Comment: Well those aren't the source and destination folders shown in your code. Strange. Are you sure you're running the right version of the code?

Comment: @ADyson  , hi. I have placed the result of echoing out $source, $newName, $destination and $newName in the original question. I also move the script to the parent directory which has sub directories of room and room/DTGLA.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite following you. My point was that if your code says `$source = "/home/bytec/public_html/apps/conf/conf_images/room";`, then it's impossible for `echo $source;` to output just `/room/`- unless you've changed the code from what is shown above?

Comment: @ADyson sorry, When I move the script to the "conf_images" directory I failed to change the location in the original question.

Comment: Hm. If the PHP script is in conf_images, then the paths need to be relative to that, so should be just `$source = "room";
$destination = "room/DTGLA";` I'd expect.

Comment: Thanks. I will look at that

Comment: @ADyson Hi, Many thanks for all your help. The code is working but falling over when there is not a file name match between the results of the SQL query and the results of room content. I will try and figure it our. Again, thanks for all your time.

Comment: No problem. I wrote the answer below. For the incorrect filename you might want to employ https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php to check before attempting to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PHP script is in the `conf_images` folder, then the paths need to be relative to that, so should be just

```
$source = "room"; 
$destination = "room/DTGLA";
```